# Does a rotational convolutional filter exist in neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

Traditionally, a convolutional filter is one where you take a matrix of numbers, multiply it with a subset of the data, and then sum it up. Then you move the filter left to right and top to bottom in a sweeping fashion to generate a smaller (or equal) grid.

But I wonder if there are filters that work in rotations meaning, consider a 2x2 filter containing these parameters.

```
a, b
d, c
```

And consider a 4x4 input data. Normally, in the CNN world, after applying the filter to the input, I would get a 3x3 output, which is the result of the sweeping I described earlier.

Now say, instead of sweeping across, I would like to rotate the weight before I apply, and I do not do sweeping, I rotate the matrix for each of the 4 corners in the 4x4 input.

Meaning, I would apply to the top-left these values

```
a, b
d, c
```

then to bottom-left these values which is the above rotated

```
b, c
a, d
```

then to the bottom-right

```
c, d
b, a
```

then to the top-right

```
d, a
c, b
```

so I end with another 2x2 matrix after applying the above filter to the 4x4 input.

Does such filter have a name already?

Comment: You might need to do your own coding of the software implementation, but nothing keeps this from being a viable neural network that shares CNN’s idea of weight sharing and dropping parameters. [Perhaps start by drawing out your filter layer like I show here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/409172/247274).

Comment: I figured out a pretty clever way to use existing CNN filters. I just have to wrangle my data.

Answer (score 0):

I think group CNN is close. It has rotation and symmetry